# Overriding object's toString in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, prototypal-inheritance

I was playing around with the toString method and when I tried to override a function's toString method, I could see the effect when I tried console.log-ging it. http://jsbin.com/bigocijuqo/1/edit?js,console.

```
function greet(){
  console.log("Hello!");
}
console.log(greet);

greet.toString = function () {
   return "Overridden toString";
};
console.log(greet);
```

produces

```
function greet(){
window.runnerWindow.proxyConsole.log("Hello!");
}
Overridden toString
```

However, when I tried the same with objects, it doesn't seem to be taking effect. http://jsbin.com/jebunakibi/1/edit?js,console

```
var ray = {
  'name': 'Ray',
  'fav_food': 'Carrots'
};

console.log(ray);

ray.toString = function () {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I loooove " + this.fav_food;
};

console.log(ray);
```

produces

```
[object Object] {
  fav_food: "Carrots",
  name: "Ray"
}
[object Object] {
  fav_food: "Carrots",
  name: "Ray",
  toString: function () {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I loooove " + this.fav_food;
}
}
```

I expected the second console.log would print

```
My name is Ray and I loooove Carrots
```

I even tried changing the toString method in Object.prototype, but it's still not taking any effect. Can somebody explain what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  Chrome [**ignores**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/1wTDLb20xac) the `toString()` method in `console.log()` output.

If you did `alert(ray)` instead, you would see "My name is Ray and I loooove Carrots."

To see the same thing in the console, do this:

```
console.log(ray.toString());
```

… or this:

```
console.log(ray + '');
```

---

You could create a new `console` function for just this purpose:

```
console.say= function(s) {
  console.log(s + '');
}
```

**Example:**

```js
console.say= function(s) {
  console.log(s + '');
}

var ray = {
  'name': 'Ray',
  'fav_food': 'Carrots'
};

ray.toString = function () {
  return "My name is " + this.name + " and I loooove " + this.fav_food;
};

console.say(ray); //My name is Ray and I loooove Carrots
```

Comment: Thanks, however, I'm a little confused why it's not the same for functions? With greet, when I said console.log(greet); the toString function gets called and whatever that returns is what we see in the console.

Comment: Now that's a good question, why it works for functions but not other objects.

Comment: I would imagine Chrome uses some *internal* representation-construction. This allows it to 'browse' objects and to maintain an accurate object graph view, even in the light of modified prototypes. Other browsers like FF and IE will implictly perform a toString, and they require `console.dir` to get behavior similar to that in Chrome's `console.log`. Developer tools are developer tools; the behavior is implementation-defined and quirks/differences observed with such should be dismissed from other JavaScript behavior.

Comment: @user2864740, I agree, and it's probably a *good* thing that Chrome acts that way.  When debugging, it's often best to see actual data structures.  Interesting that Chrome doesn't apply that behavior to functions, however.

Comment: @user2864740, I see that in chrome, your example, indeed results in "hi!"!

Comment: @ArunKumarNagarajan Oh, indeed! I must have messed something up when I tried it locally. Thanks for pointing that out.